# How to use hashSet properly? (moving from c++ to java)

Tags: java, android, hashset

I'm approaching (after c++) to java and, in particular, with android app development (Android studio) but I've some trouble with hashSet usage.
Here's is the issue: I cannot find a way to store map's keys obtained from "keySet()" method in any container; I tried to store keys in a string vector or a list but an error occurs. How can I fix that?

This is a piece of code:

```
 private void fillMap(Map<String, String> map, String[] strings){

    String str;

    map.put("Question1", "answer1");
    map.put("Question2", "answer2");
    map.put("Question3", "answer3");

    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();


}
```

As you can see I created a map whose keys are questions and its values are answers. Then I created a Set where to put all the keys; The problem is that I would try to store the content of the set in an ordered container but everything I tried gives me error.

Comment: Can you show some code? Your question/problem is unclear.

Comment: Here is a piece of code. It is a function created outside the "onCreate" part, where all structures were created. I set the second parameter of the function as String[] cause I Thought it was possible transfer "keys" content into a string vector

Comment: Are you trying to put the contents of `keys` into `strings`?

Comment: I was trying to, but it gives me error; 
But i'm not interested to the type of the container so far, in fact I think I'll use a list as suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a `Map<String, Integer>` then its `keySet()` is a `Set<String>` an interface derived from the even more general `Collection<String>`. This collection you can add to everything.

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(keys); // 1
list.sort();

Collections.addAll(list, keys); // or 2
Collections.sort(list); 

SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(keys);
```

And a warning to a C++ programmer: Vector is a very old inefficient class; use ArrayList instead, hence variables, parameters, result types List.

Comment: Thank you so much, you were so much helpful! 
Regarding C++ thanks for the advice, I'll avoid vector usage!